# Wake up & Woke up

Tags: difference, tense

What's the different between 'wake up' & 'woke up'?

Which grammar part used in it? & How can I understand this type of word? Which means different situation?

Answer (score 0):

I always wake up at 8 a.m.
I woke up at 10 a.m. yesterday.

woke up is the past tense of wake up.
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wake?s=t